# Complex Multi-level Laravel4 Eloquent Relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to print a page that shows all users who registered for an event. Users are defined as "officers" if they have privilege to attend, and every officer is a student (but a student can be an officer of any position in more than one club).

Here are my relationships:

```
class OfficerEvent extends Eloquent{

protected $table = "officerEvents";
public $timestamps = false; 
protected $primaryKey = "oeventID";

public function rsvp()
{
    return $this->hasMany('OfficerEventRSVP', 'oeventID');
} 
 }
```

**Officer RSVPs to events:**

```
class OfficerEventRSVP extends Eloquent{

protected $table = "officerEventRSVP";
public $timestamps = true; 
protected $primaryKey = "rsvpID";

public function officerEvent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('OfficerEvent', 'oeventID');
}

public function officer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Officer', 'cwid', 'officerCWID');
}
}
```

**Table of officers:**

```
class Officer extends Eloquent{

protected $table = "officers";
public $timestamps = false;
protected $primaryKey = "cwid";

public function club()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Club', 'clubID');
}

public function student()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Student', 'cwid');
}

public function officerEventRSVP()
{
    return $this->hasMany('OfficerEventRSVP', 'cwid', 'officerCWID');
}

}
```

**Table of students (all officers are students):**

```
class Student extends Eloquent{

protected $table = "students";
public $timestamps = false;
protected $primaryKey = "cwid";

public function officer()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Officer', 'cwid', 'cwid');
}

}
```

I'm getting stuck trying to make a query that a) gets all events and rsvps, then b) gets officer info (Name, email) from those RSVPs.

I've gotten this so far, but I keep getting a white page when I run it:

```
    $officerEvents = OfficerEvent::with('rsvp')->get();

    foreach($officerEvents as $officerEvent)
    {
     foreach ($officerEvent->rsvp as $rsvp) {
        foreach ($rsvp->officer() as $officer) {
            var_dump($officer->student());
        }
      }   
    }
```

Comment: Your first sentence `every officer is a student` is a perfect premise for polymorphism, ie. `Officer` should inherit from `Student`

Answer (score 0):

If every Officer is a Student the relationship is hasOne, not hasMany. The syntax remain the same, but it expects a direct one on one connection.

Have you correctly set those keys as indexes in migrations?

Comment: Yes, but a student can be an officer in more than one club. They could be secretary in Club A while also holding the President in Club B. 

Indices were set correctly, yes.